# How to limit the number of match by regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
"It was in 1990. Then it was in 1992. Then it was in 2000. Then it was in 2005. Then it was in 2010."
```

I have the following regexp to match a year in the string:

```
\d{4}
```

It matches all years present in the string. What I want is to limit the regexp to only the first match, so that it should give me only '1990'. I am using the following code in pytho:

```
import re
s =  "It was in 1990. Then it was in 1992. Then it was in 2000. Then it was in 2005.      Then it was in 2010."
print re.findall(r"\d{4}", s)
['1990', '1992', '2000', '2005', '2010'] # output
```

I know that I can get the the first one by adding [0] as in the following:

```
print re.findall(r"\d{4}", s)[0]
1990 # output
```

But I am specially looking for a regex pattern to get this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
>>> import re
>>> s =  "It was in 1990. Then it was in 1992. Then it was in 2000. Then it was in 2005.      Then it was in 2010."
>>> re.search("\d{4}", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01939AA0>
>>> re.search("\d{4}", s).group()
'1990'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `re.finditer(r"\d{4}", s)`

```
In [38]: import re

In [39]: s =  "It was in 1990. Then it was in 1992. Then it was in 2000. Then it was in 2005.      Then it was in 2010."

In [40]: ret = re.finditer(r"\d{4}", s)

In [41]: ret.next().group()
Out[41]: '1990'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use re.search instead.  It returns a MatchObject or null.  you can get the matched text from the MatchObject by calling group(0) on it.